# Find which process accesses registry?

Tags: c#

Ok if anyone can solve this they must be a genius because its nowhere on the web!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

This program detects registry accesses and tells you which process did it.

Does anyone know how i can do this? I can detect changes, but i cant get the process.

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI: The sysinternals guys are pretty much geniuses when it comes to Windows.

Answer (score 3):

It's done by hooking system calls. It hooks calls to `RegOpenKey` (etc) and records all the information about the process accessing the registry before passing the call to the *real* `RegOpenKey`.

See [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) for a library that makes it *relatively* easy to write API hooks in Windows.

**However**, when I say "easy", I actually mean "here be monsters!" API hooking is not for the faint of heart and you should have a very good working knowledge of the internals of Windows before you attempt it.

Comment: Ah thanks for that! So essentially i am going to 'grab' a key once a change has been detected and then hook it? Or do i need to do this hooking before the change has been detected?

Sorry, this is all so knew to me. I was just used to PInvoke earlier today and i've ended up learning about hooking!

Thanks

ps Which of the easyhook files do i need to include in my project? The .h and the .dll?

Comment: You hook the RegOpenKey function (say) and then whenever a process calls RegOpenKey, your function is called instead of the real one. Then you record the parameters that were passed in and hand off to the *real* RegOpenKey to do the actual work. As I said, this is not for the faint of heart, and to be honest I don't think you're ready to start looking at API hooking if you've only just learnt about P/Invoke today... Mark Russinovich (author of Process Monitor) has been doing Windows programming for 15 years and is an operating systems expert...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find out what's doing it, then you can use ProcessMonitor, or one of the other derivations of those tools from Sysinternals, now run by Microsoft as Winternals.  See the list of programs [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027.aspx).

If you want to write a program to do it, you'll have to hook the registry access functions.  The source code for that can be found in archives of the Sysinternals tools.  It doesn't seem to be available anymore with the program.